# is this Service Worker configuration risky?

Tags: next.js, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin, service-worker-config

I am working on one e-commerce using Next JS. I am trying to improve the page load speed, this website loads a lot of JS files due to the amount of third parties vendors it has (and can't delete). I am planning to cache some static assets with Service Workers.

I am going to use the library [next-offline](https://github.com/hanford/next-offline) that uses the workbox-webpack-plugin. This is the configuration I am planning to use:

```
workboxOpts: {
              swDest: '../public/service-worker.js',
              maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 20000000,
              runtimeCaching: [
                {
                  urlPattern: /https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/icon[\w\-_\/\.\:\?\=\&\+]*/,
                  handler: 'CacheFirst',
                  options: {
                    cacheName: 'google-fonts',
                    expiration: {
                      maxEntries: 10,
                      maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 1 month
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  urlPattern: /[\w\-_\/\.:]*\.(jpeg|png|jpg|ico|svg)\??.*/,
                  handler: 'CacheFirst',
                  options: {
                    cacheName: 'cache-img',
                    expiration: {
                      maxEntries: 15,
                      maxAgeSeconds: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 2 days
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  urlPattern: /^((?!monetate).)*\.(js)$/,
                  handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
                },
                {
                  urlPattern: /\/(browse.*|catalogsearch.*)$/,
                  handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
                },
              ],
            },
```

So, my questions are the following:

1. **do you think that this configuration is risky? Would you change something?** I mean, I had several problems in the past with Service Workers caching JS files where I had to set a version for every file to make it work. However, now it seems that [workbox fixed this issue](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching).
2. **Should I set a maxAge for the Stale while revalidation strategy?** I want to revalidate the data every time the user reload the page. However [here](https://web.dev/stale-while-revalidate/) it says that it will use the cache without revalidate until the maxAge time is complete. **What happens if I don't set in the workbox settings a maxAge?**

I am testing this on a Vercel deploy (in a testing environment) and it seems it is working fine and I am thinking to move it to production.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use next-offline(i haven't used it much), or you can go ahead with using workbox-webpack-plugin. There is take cares of what file to refetch after caching(uses revision & hash(on url)).
**Read this section :** https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#how_workbox-precaching_works